# Derivative and divison [SOLVED]

Tags: derivatives

[**SOLUTION:** Like [Tom-Himler](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/457359/tom-himler) said: numerator is wrong because chain-rule was not followed]

I am reading, [Calculus Made Easy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculus_Made_Easy) and there is this example on page 73:

$$\omega = \frac{\sqrt{1-\theta^2}}{1+\theta}$$ (notice square-root is only in numerator). The author made the calculation easier by cancelling out,  $$\omega = \sqrt\frac{1-\theta}{1+\theta}$$ (notice square-root is in both numerator and denominator) and then taking the derivative $$\frac{d\omega}{d\theta} = \frac{-1}{(1+\theta)\sqrt{1-\theta^2}}$$

But when I do the derivative  without cancelling out, it does not come out to be correct.

Quotient rules states that the derivative of a function that is the ratio of two different functions is  $$\frac{d}{dx}\frac{u(x)}{v(x)} = \frac{(v \frac{du}{dx}) -(u\frac{dv}{dx})}{v^2}$$

Hence $u = (1 - \theta^2), v = (1+\theta)$

$$\frac{d\omega}{d\theta}$$ evaluates to

1. *Numerator*   $$\frac{(1+\theta)}{2\cdot \sqrt{1-\theta^2}}  - \sqrt
       {1 - \theta^2}\cdot 1$$
2. *Denominator*  $$(1+\theta)^2 = (1+\theta)(1+\theta)$$
3. *Simplifying numerator*: $$\frac{(1+\theta) - 2(1-\theta^2)}{2\sqrt{1
           - \theta^2}}$$
4. *Putting back numerator and denominator*  $$\frac{(1+\theta)
           -2(1+\theta)(1-\theta)}{2(1+\theta)(1+\theta)\sqrt{1-\theta^2}}\\
        \frac{1-2(1-\theta)}{2(1+\theta)\sqrt{1-\theta^2}}\\
        \frac{1-2+2\theta}{2(1+\theta)\sqrt{1-\theta^2}}\\
        \frac{-1+2\theta}{2(1+\theta)\sqrt{1-\theta^2}}$$

This does not match the answer the book gave.

Where did I go wrong ?

Comment: Don't forget to use the chain rule. You're numerator is wrong.

Comment: `$\frac{numerator}{denominator}$` renders as $\frac{\text{numerator}}{\text{denominator}}$.  It isn't *that* complicated.  And use `$\sqrt{stuff}$` to get $\sqrt{\text{stuff}}$.

Comment: @Tom-Himler -- Chain rule solved it. Thanks

Comment: You can use nested fractions in that case: `$\frac{\frac{Expression_1}{Expression_2}-\frac{Expression_3}{Expression_4}}{Denominator}$` yields $\frac{\frac{Expression_1}{Expression_2}-\frac{Expression_3}{Expression_4}}{Denominator}$.

Comment: @Clayton Thanks, that is what I needed

Comment: No worries. LaTeX/MathJax can seem overwhelming/cumbersome the first time you look at it, but once you get some experience with it, it's much better for you and any of your readers.

Comment: @TomHimler: You ought to write your comment as an answer so you can earn some reputation, as well as allowing the OP to accept your answer. I've posted an answer with your comment as CW for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't forget to use the chain rule. Your numerator is wrong. -Tom Himler (from comments).

Comment: Oof just realized I used you're instead of your.

Comment: =:-D , it was nice anyway